# MatLab - How to solve an indefinite integral and then define the limits?

Tags: matlab, math, integral

I have an model to evaluate a thermodinamical process, it is made with Mathcad and I need it in MatLab.

It is a big equation that uses an integral thousand of times, each temperature uses an definite integral.
If I solve each time, the result is the same as Mathcad, but it takes hours, if I solve only once, it takes less than a second, but the result is wrong.
I split the equation and found that the error is in the part that is in the code.

How should I write my code to solve only one time the and get the right result?

```
clc
clear

FrCrist = FCrystFastWrong();
FrCrist = FCrystSlowRight();

function [Fvpa] = FCrystSlowRight()
    tic;
    syms T;
    Part4 = (10^(-4.27+(3961/(T-751))));

    i = 0;
    for TempN = 996:1100
        i = i+1;
        TC(i) = TempN;
        FintDef = int(Part4,T,[1000 TempN]);
        Fvpa(i) = double(vpa(FintDef));
    end
    toc

    plot(TC,Fvpa)
end

function [Fvpa] = FCrystFastWrong()
    tic;
    syms T;
    Part4 = (10^(-4.27+(3961/(T-751))));
    Fint = int(Part4,T);

    qc = arrayfun(@char, Fint, 'uniform', 0);
    qc = erase(qc,"int");
    qc = erase(qc,", T");
    qc = str2sym(qc);

    f = inline(qc,'T');

    i = 0;
    for TempN = 996:1667
        i = i+1;
        TC(i) = TempN;
        Solve(i) = f(TempN)-f(1000);
        Fvpa(i) = Solve(i);
    end
    toc

    plot(TC,Fvpa)
end
```

Comment: What are the limits of integration? Is it from 1000 to TempN (the loop variable)? Did you checked the [integral](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/integral.html) function to do numerical integration (symbolic evaluation is very time consuming)?

Comment: The limit is between a given temperature (for this example 1000 Kelvin) and the N Temperature (ex: 996 to 1000, 997 to 1000, 998 to 1000... 1773 to 1000).

Comment: This was not what I was thinking, but it solve the problem, the elapsed time was 3 times the elapsed for only solving once, but it was much faster than the "FCrystSlowRight".
Thanks!

Comment: Avoid symbolic calculations at all costs!! Always look for the MATLAB documentation on how to do what you want numerically! :)

Comment: If you want to stick with the symbolic calculation, you can do it once between two variable limits (and store the result). You will be solving the integral once and then substitute the variable limits for the ones that you want to solve. Your integral is easy enough to be solved fast, the issue is that you are using the symbolic solver hundreds of time.

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, but that is not the full integral, the integral is huge, I didn't know about this difference with Symbolic and Numerical solver, using the numerical the problem was solved.